# Where are imperishable personalities from Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, history, philosophy, belief

The characters listed below are Chiranjeevi's or imperishable personalities from Dwaaparayuga that means they are immortal. So where do they exist in Kaliyug? Is there any evidence or documents available?

```
 1. Ashwathama, 
 2. King Mahabali, 
 3. Veda Vyasa,
 4. Hanuman, 
 5. Vibhishana,     
 6. Kripacharya, 
 7. Parashurama
```

are the `seven` death-defying or imperishable personalities.

Comment: 'So where do they exist in Kaliyuga?' - they all are most likely dead. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39959/2995) answer. The 'chiranjeevi' concept is a creation of the Puranas, not found in the Vedas.