# Some questions regarding Valmiki Ramayana

Tags: ramayana, tamil, agastya

- Are only male vanaras monkey like? In all shows and serials wife of vanaras are shown as humans
- Is there no enounter with humans in South India is Ramayana?
- Arent vanaras mlechhas since they are not humans?
- Since only Kshatriyas are allowed to fight are all vanaras kshatriyas?
- The amount of time mentioned is to be taken at face value or as exaggeration for poetry? Dashrath is said to have waited 6000 years for children. Ram and Sita are said to have ruled for 10000 years together before Ram banished Sita. Ravanas age is said to be in crores.
- Any mention on women warriors?
- I was watching Ramananad Sagar's Ramayan. In one scene while taling about Rishi Agastya Ram said he gave rules for Tamil. Is this mentioned by Valmiki or in Ramcharitmanas?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: Vanaras are not mlecchas.

Comment: People used to live longer in previous Yugas.

Comment: "Dashratha is said to have waited 6000 years for children. Rama and Sita are said to have ruled for 10000 years" - see [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39959/2995) answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions of the OP have been reproduced here.

> - Are only male vanaras monkey like? In all shows and serials wife of vanaras are shown as humans
> - Is there no enounter with humans in South India is Ramayana?
> - Arent vanaras mlechhas since they are not humans?
> - Since only Kshatriyas are allowed to fight are all vanaras kshatriyas?
> - The amount of time mentioned is to be taken at face value or as exaggeration for poetry? Dashrath is said to have waited 6000 years
>     for children. Ram and Sita are said to have ruled for 10000 years
>     together before Ram banished Sita. Ravanas age is said to be in
>     crores.
> - Any mention on women warriors?
> - I was watching Ramananad Sagar's Ramayan. In one scene while taling about Rishi Agastya Ram said he gave rules for Tamil. Is this
>     mentioned by Valmiki or in Ramcharitmanas?

---

Let me provide answers, point-wise.

1. (a)  Valmiki introduces Vanaras in the Aranya Kanda.  Kabandha, who was eliminated by Sri Rama and Lakshmana, advices, after regaining his original form, the latter to approach Sugriva, a Vanana.

> श्रूयताम् राम वक्ष्यामि सुग्रीवो नाम ***वानरः*** | भ्रात्रा निरस्तः
>   क्रुद्धेन वालिना शक्र सूनुना || ३-७२-११
>
> "Oh, Rama, listen what I tell... ***a vAnara*** is there by name Sugreeva,
>   who is vengefully reneged by his brother Vali, the son of Indra.

From this part onwards, Valmiki sometimes used the word कपिम् also.  ***It is not clear*** from the usage of vAnara - वानरः, whether Valmiki was referring to monkeys or a separate race, having tail.

b) Valmiki didn't describe the women of vanaras as monkeys.

---

2. Sabari and Swayamprabha were introduced in the Aranya and Kishkinda Kandas as human only.
3. vAnaras are not mlechhas.  They were also learned.  Sri Hanuman was described as conversant in 3 Veda.

> न अन् ऋग्वेद विनीतस्य न अ--यजुर्वेद धारिणः | न अ--साम वेद विदुषः
>   शक्यम् एवम् विभाषितुम् || ४-३-२८
>
> "Nay...the non-knower of Rig Veda, or the non-rememberer of Yajur
>   Veda, or the non-scholar of Saama Veda... can possibly, or truly speak
>   this way...

Moreover, Sri Hanuman was described as follower of ***dakshinAchara - follower of Vedic way*** of life by Valmiki

अञ्जलिं प्राङ्मुखः कृत्वा पवनायात्मयोओनयो |
ततो हि ववृधे गन्तुं **दक्षिणो** दक्षिणां दिश्म् ||

---

4) Vanaras are also warriors.  kshatriya indicates the quality of a human being, who has the ability and dareness to fight, but does not indicate a race or sect.

5) The normal life span of a human beings is around 100 years.  However, some might have lived longer life also.

The legendary saint [Sri Trailanga Swami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trailanga), lived for 280 years.

Whether people like Dasaratha really lived for 60,000 years or not cannot be discussed and understood now.  It is a disputed topic.

6) Women warriors were not mentioned in Ramayana, except that Kaikeyi assisted King Dasaratha in a war between Gods and Demons.

7) Sage Agasthya was mentioned in Aranya Kanda of Ramayana.  However, there is no such reference provided in Ramayana as to his laying down rules to Tamil Language.

Comment: thankyou. 
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/39969/19725 this ans clears the female vanara part

Comment: "Women warriors were not mentioned in Ramayana"-- TV serial shows many like 1) Tadka, 2) Sursa, 3) one who captures Hanuman's shade, 4) one who guards Lanka named Lankini etc...Doesn't VRM mentions about them?

Answer (score 0):

- Are only male vanaras monkey like? In all shows and serials wife of vanaras are shown as humans?

I don't know why TV serials show this. In actual Ramayana, female monkeys are also mentioned.

> "Let monkey-shaped progeny equalling Vishnu's valour be procreated from the physiques of prominent apsara-s and gandharva-s, from the girls of yaksha-s and pannaga-s, and also thus from the bodies of kinnaraa-s, she-vidyaadharaa-s, she-riksha-s and **she-monkeys**, and they shall be wizards of miracles and audacious ones, in travel they shall have air's speed, bestowed with intellect they shall be the knowers of ideation, and with their divine physique they shall be ineliminable, they shall be endowed with all the assaultive aspects of all missiles, and they shall be untiring in their efforts, like you who thrive on amrita, the ambrosia, unmindful of thirst and hunger. [1-17-3, 4, 5, 6]

Not only female monkeys, but female langoors, bears etc. are also mentioned.

> Some of the vanara-s endowed with superior valour are born to **female langoors,** and like that some more to **female bears** and kinnaraa-s. [1:17:20b,21a]

- Arent vanaras mlechhas since they are not humans?

No. Vanaras were like monkeys but they were humans. It will be clear with this verse.

> When Brahma addressed them thus, those gods have agreed to his order and accordingly started to parent sons in **the semblance of monkeys.** [1-17-8]

Here, ***vaana ruupiNam*** means *semblance to monkeys* is used. It means monkeys were already existed before their creation. Vanaras were Aryans and Noble man.

> सुप्ता इव पुनर् उत्थाय आर्य पुत्र इति वादिनी |
>   रुरोद सा पतिम् दृष्ट्वा सम्वीतम् मृत्यु दामभिः || ४-१९-२७
>
> On getting up as though reawakened from sleep she saw her husband bound fast by the strings of death, and then she wailingly addressed him as, "oh, **son of Arya**..." [4-19-27]

Tara called Bali son of Arya itself prove that they were Arya not Malecha.

- Since only Kshatriyas are allowed to fight are all vanaras kshatriyas?

I think they were Kshatriya. Vanaras were created to help Rama and fight with Ravana.

> "Let mighty and guise changing helpmates be procreated to that truth abiding and valorous Vishnu who is the well-wisher of all of us. [1-17-2]
>
> The earth is thus suffused with those mighty army generals of Vanara race whose physiques resembled the clusters of clouds and peaks of mountains, and who have emerged for **the reason of helping Rama.** [1-17-37]

- The amount of time mentioned is to be taken at face value or as exaggeration for poetry? Dashrath is said to have waited 6000 years for children. Ram and Sita are said to have ruled for 10000 years together before Ram banished Sita. Ravanas age is said to be in crores.

Sorry, but I failed to find any reference like it. I think it is not present in Valmiki Ramayana.

- Any mention on women warriors?

Yes, Lord Rama [fought](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga26/bala_26_frame.htm) with Tadka. I will try to find more female warriors.

- I was watching Ramananad Sagar's Ramayan. In one scene while taling about Rishi Agastya Ram said he gave rules for Tamil. Is this mentioned by Valmiki or in Ramcharitmanas?

Sage Agastya was a sage of South India. He is known as compiler of Tamil grammar. I think that's why Rama called him like this.

- Is there no enounter with humans in South India is Ramayana?

Lord Rama met with Sage Agastya, Shabri and Vanaras (As I already cleared that they were humans.)

Comment: thanks alot. cleared many doubts.On the Tamil point, I meant did Ram mention tamil in valmiki ramayana, since the show uses a large number of versions of Ramayana. http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga20/balasans20.htm#Verse10-> Dashraths age. similarly it is mentioned Rama was 10000 when luv and khush were 12